# How to reduce the size of winform installer setup file?

Tags: winforms, setup-deployment, microsoft-sync-framework

I am working with win form  C# application. My application required prerequisites like 
1.Dot net framework 4.0 =48 MB
2.Sql server Express =186 MB
3.Microsoft sync framework -20 MB

And
Application installer size =8 MB

Now,installer size is 270 MB with prerequisites.

How i minimized the size of installer,Can i remove sync framework from installer ? or change sql express version? what will be the alternative?

is it any other alternative available please suggest any alternative..!

Thank..!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bundle all your prerequisite along with your MSI there is no way to reduce the size of your package. But alternative solution is to ask the users to install the prerequisites separately and within `Launch Condition` of the MSI you can add conditions to check if those prerequisites are installed if not you can display appropriate message saying particular prerequsite component is not installed.

[Launch Condition Management in Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ay12wede%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Example

- [SQL Server 2008 Express Launch Condition](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/76510104-1be5-4159-a152-4d02fbca0fd0/sql-server-2008-express-launch-condition?forum=winformssetup)